# Getting "invalid api key" for POSTs but not GETs

Tags: api, rest, authentication, post

using the provided code for Coinbase Prime Authorization:

```
import requests
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
import http.client
import json
import os
from requests.auth import AuthBase
API_PASSPHRASE = os.getenv("API_PASSPHRASE")
API_KEY = os.getenv("API_KEY")
API_SECRET = os.getenv("API_SECRET")

# Create custom authentication for Coinbase API
class CoinbasePrimeAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, key, secret, passphrase):
        self.api_key = key
        self.secret_key = secret
        self.passphrase = passphrase
    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
        message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url.split('?')[0] + str(request.body or '')
        signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
        signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature).decode()
        request.headers.update({
            'X-CB-ACCESS-SIGNATURE': signature_b64,
            'X-CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'X-CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
            'X-CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
        return request
auth = CoinbasePrimeAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, API_PASSPHRASE)
```

Then continuing with the get request that completes successfully, letting me store the IDs

```
api_url = 'https://api.prime.coinbase.com'
resp = requests.get(api_url + f'/v1/portfolios', auth=auth)
resp_json = json.loads(resp.text)
PORTFOLIO_ID = resp_json['portfolios'][0]['id']
ENTITY_ID = resp_json['portfolios'][0]['entity_id']
ORGANIZATION_ID = resp_json['portfolios'][0]['organization_id']
```

But trying to do a post request to create a wallet...

```
payload = {"portfolio_id": PORTFOLIO_ID,
           "name":"testwallet",
           "symbol":"btc",
           "wallet_type":"TRADING"
           }
resp4 = requests.post(api_url + f'/v1/portfolios/{PORTFOLIO_ID}/wallets', json = payload, auth = auth)
```

fails with a `401` response, "invalid api key"
Clearly, I don't have an invalid api key with the previous request working fine

If I don't include the `payload` argument it fails with `invalid argument: name`, so looks like its checking that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why the original error was `api key not found` instead of some malformed request, but the problem is in `str(request.body or '')`

`request.body` will be a bytetype. To change to string, the correct syntax is `.decode()`, not `str(...)`

`decode()` throws an error on nonetype, so catch it like

```
def __call__(self, request):
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    if request.body is not None:
        the_body = request.body.decode()
    else:
        the_body = ""
    message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url.split('?')[0] + the_body
```